# Concussion question - Reopen request

Tags: support, closed-questions

[How to get a concussed person back up to speed quick?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11779/how-to-get-a-concussed-person-back-up-to-speed-quick) got supplied with requested details, so that the scope seems narrowed enough not to be "idea generation" anymore. Currently it has 4 reopen votes but it fell low enough it doesn't get any traffic.

Could someone either provide the last reopen vote, or tell what else should I do to make it fit?

Comment: I would recommend that you bring this up first in [chat]; there are usually several high-rep users there. Little need to keep it around more or less forever on Meta...

Comment: I still don't see what concussion treatment has to do with world building. But others might think otherwise.

Comment: The question has been re-opened.